# rails 2.3.10 open_session - method missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to write some tests for an old app:

```
open_session do |sess|
  sess.post "/shop/cart/add", :product_id => 687, :quantity => 1
  assert_equal '/shop/cart', path
end
```

I just need to test the checkout process but the app needs session data to do so. When I use open_session I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `open_session' for #<OrderTest:0x10706cf68>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm ok I was using

```
class OrderTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
```

instead of

```
class OrderTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
```